# How to send HttpPostedFileBase to S3 via AWS SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I'm having some trouble getting uploaded files to save to S3.  My first attempt was:

```
Result SaveFile(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
{
    //Keys are in web.config
    var t = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
    try
    {
        t.Upload(new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = Bucket,
            InputStream = file.InputStream,
            Key = path
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Result.FailResult(ex.Message);
    }
    return Result.SuccessResult();
}
```

This throws an exception with the message: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."  I also tried copying file.InputStream to a MemoryStream, then uploading that, with the same error.
If I set the InputStream to:

```
new FileStream(@"c:\folder\file.txt", FileMode.Open)
```

then the file uploads fine.  Do I really need to save the file to disk before uploading it?

Comment: Apparently the error is caused by path starting with '/'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my working version first the upload method:

```
   public bool Upload(string filePath, Stream inputStream, double contentLength, string contentType)
    {

        try
        {
            var request = new PutObjectRequest();

            request.WithBucketName(_bucketName)
                .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
                .WithKey(filePath).InputStream = inputStream;

            request.AddHeaders(AmazonS3Util.CreateHeaderEntry("ContentType", contentType));

            _amazonS3Client.PutObject(request);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          // log or throw;
          return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I just get the stream from `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream`

(Note, this is on an older version of the Api, the `WithBucketName` syntax is no longer supported, but just set the properties directly)

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of shenku, for newer versions of SDK.

```
public bool Upload(string filePath, Stream inputStream, double contentLength, string contentType)
{
  try
  {
      var request = new PutObjectRequest();
      string _bucketName = "";

      request.BucketName = _bucketName;
      request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
      request.InputStream = inputStream;
      request.Key = filePath;
      request.Headers.ContentType = contentType;

      PutObjectResponse response = _amazonS3Client.PutObject(request);

      return true;

  }catch(Exception ex)
  {
      return false;
  }
}
```